# If I pass validation data to the fit() function, do we need model.evaluate()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

```
 history = model.fit(
        train_x, train_y,
        validation_data=(validate_x, validate_y),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        epochs=EPOCH_SIZE,
        callbacks=[callbacks_vector],
        shuffle=True,
        verbose=2
    )
```

If I pass validation data to the `fit()` function as above, do I actually need to call `model.evaluate()` later?

If I passed validation data to fit, my data is already validated. Right?

Comment: You can use `model.evaluate` on test data after training.

Comment: True but check the docs regarding what model.evaluate actually does: "Returns the loss value & metrics values for the model in test mode." https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=nightly#evaluate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `validation data` and `test data` are quite different for machine learning, check this out : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set .

And `model.evaluate()` is used on `test data`.